# Как задать переменные окружения для GUI приложений в Mac OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, sublime-text

Не могу задать переменную *path* (там пути хранятся, например, */usr/bin/*) для *gui* приложений. Как сделать так, чтобы Sublime Text во время компиляции искал в том числе и в */usr/local/bin*?

P.S. *launchd.conf* - не работает, */etc/paths* - не работает, *environment.plist* - не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение для Sublime Text (и 2 и 3 версии) можно найти на github: [ссылка](https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath)

Для Emacs'a: [ссылка](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)